# Crystal Report Issue When Deploy To IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, deployment, crystal-reports, report

I'm using crystal reports 13 with VS 2010. Everything works fine on the development machine. Once deployed the reports wont show in the browser, on the web server (windows 2008, IIS7) I have installed crystal report run time.... feel like I am missing something else.

Has anybody experienced the same issue?

Another issue I did notice was on the development machine, the crystal reports were sensitive to the browser that it was run on... with chrome the report is appear but when I use  firefox 37.0.2 it shows

[image: http://postimg.org/image/yvcyh8j4r/]

When I use IE, I get following error:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/vvm9ojlef/]

Can any one tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: looks like an encoding issue.

Comment: i not really know about encoding issue in iis. thx for response. after sufring in internet so many times and read so many article, this one is very usefull for me. maybe for someone who get same problem this link can help too https://kb.edgehosting.com/KnowledgebaseArticle53046.aspx